# How to hide Intellij IDEA top gutter in editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

There's the navigation bar and it's possible to hide it in menu. But, in the last version IntelliJ IDEA added another kinda navigation bar.

It looks like an editor gutter but placed at the top of the active editor. It show the name of the class and method with the current caret position.

Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To disable this feature, uncheck *Show breadcrumbs* in *Settings/Editor/General/Appearance*.

[Source](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-adds-breadcrumb-for-java/)