# How to remove top line breadcrumb in intellij idea editor?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I'm having an issue figuring out this display bar in IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 15.

[image]

Does anyone know what this is and/or how to turn it off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Intellij IDEA top gutter in editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560317/how-to-hide-intellij-idea-top-gutter-in-editor)

Answer (score 9):

It is known as the breadcrumb menu for current code position. For example in your image you are in the position of class Display -> method Display() (constructor) -> member anonymous ActionListner -> method actionPerformed() -> member anonymous SwingWorker. (should be verified)

To disable it from showing, Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance**

And Find and un-tick '**Show breadcrumbs**'.

You might need to restart the editor, to take this effect into action.

[image]

Comment: Or just write in the search box.

Comment: Note - I had to restart Android Studio for this to take effect.

Comment: @Kevin Thank You for noting. For me, it was not the case, and as I found in  official documentation, there was no such a thing mentioned. I think it might vary on other facts like version, OS etc. Anyway to remove any suspect, I added your point to the answer. :))

Comment: Note that this option is missing in current (year of posting) versions of Idea and Android Studio. There's no other way I know of to remove the breadcrumb menu.

Comment: I'm about 3 years late to this party, but the Idea UI has changed a little, so I thought worth adding here. 
The "breadcrumb" also features in the "Navigation Bar" which sits above your editor window but below the File/Edit/View .. menu. Do a search [shift x 3] for "Navigation Bar" to get the keyboard shortcut to toggle its visibility.